# Laravel Eloquent HasMany works on localhost (macos) but not Ubuntu server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So on my macbook running Mojave, using MAMP installed via homebrew, php7.1.23, serving using `php artisan serve`, my code below runs fine:

```
    public function integrations(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Integration');
    }
```

This is in the User model. When I'm testing on a small Ubuntu 18.04.2 server with nginx, php-fpm 7.2.19 with the same database the code returns `0`. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seeded your database with the same values as localhost?

Comment: I used mysqldump, so its the same database; for other reasons I didn't use laravels database manager

Comment: Does your database have the exact same schema? I'm not sure if Eloquent depends on it, but it could be something like misconfigured primary or foreign keys

Comment: @PtrTon at first I actually merged two databases together, but then I took a mysqldump of the exact database on my ubuntu instance and ran it on my local machine and it worked fine.